# В чем заключается разница между функциями в WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

В данный момент познаю WinAPI и столкнулся с недопониманием.
В чем разница между функциями `CreateFile` `CreateFileA` `Createfile2`

По моему мнению они все реализуют один и тот же функционал. Так для чего нам три функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateFile` это define-токен, расширяется в `CreateFileW` для UNICODE (16-бит), или в `CreateFileA` ANSI (8-бит). Последние - это функции, у них одна разница в типе параметра имени файла (lpFileName):  `LPCWSTR` или `LPCSTR` соответственно. А функция `CreateFile2` имеет меньше входных параметров, а тип имени файла `LPCWSTR` (как у `CreateFileW`, для UNICODE).

Вот для сравнения их сигнатуры (из файла заголовка <fileapi.h>:

```
HANDLE
CreateFileA(
    _In_ LPCSTR lpFileName,
    _In_ DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    _In_ DWORD dwShareMode,
    _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    _In_ DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    _In_ DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    _In_opt_ HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );

HANDLE
CreateFileW(
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    _In_ DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    _In_ DWORD dwShareMode,
    _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    _In_ DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    _In_ DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    _In_opt_ HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );

#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE

HANDLE
CreateFile2(
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    _In_ DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    _In_ DWORD dwShareMode,
    _In_ DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    _In_opt_ LPCREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS pCreateExParams
    );
```

Практически, проще и удобнее пользоваться `CreateFile2`, более новой и простой функцией. Особенно, если учесть, что в русскоязычной сфере, скорее всего имена файлов будут содержать UNICODE символы (напр. "мой_файл_данных.txt").

Примерно так:

`HANDLE h = CreateFile2(L"./мой_файл.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0x0, CREATE_ALWAYS, nullptr);`